# Default index.html page for any virtual host

Tags: apache, centos7

I have configured some vhost like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias test.mywebsite.com  
  DocumentRoot /hosting/test  
  <Directory "/hosting/test">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
   Require all granted
  </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache/ssl/mywebsite.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache/ssl/mywebsite.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Now i need to display a default webpage if domain root folder not have any index page like index.php or index.html.

Actualy if open wesite it return 403 forbidden if index.html/php is not present.

My idea is;

Folder site no index.html/php show:
defaultwebpage.html in /etc/var/http/hdocs/default.html

How to this?

Apache config.conf is configured with default root but if put the index.html here it is not displayed in case of lack.

```
DocumentRoot "/data/www/default"
<Directory "/data/www/default">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>

<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the ErrorDocument thing to redirect all 404 to a certain default page? If that default page is outside your webroot use alias to bring it in.

So

Alias /specialindex /etc/var/http/hdocs/

and

ErrorDocument 403 /specialindex/default.html

Looks strange, but should work. But, catches all 403 of course...

Comment: Is a good idea but i have some website i cant set my 404 for all, but i remember in my last lamp installation from repo remi php-fpm 7.1 apache is configured with default html is not present on domain folder, so i think is possibile my solution =)

Comment: Crazy! Never have seen such a construct before :) However, if it works for you...

Comment: And, for unknown reason I was refering to 404 while you were talking about 403...need to edit my answer...